# if $ax^n+by^n=1+2^{n+1}$ find the value $x^a+y^b$

Tags: calculus

let $a,b,c,y$ are real numbers,and for any positive integer such
$$ax^n+by^n=1+2^{n+1}$$
Find the value 
$$x^a+y^b$$

My idea: let $n=0$ then we have
$$a+b=3$$
let $n=1$,then we have
$$ax+by=5$$
then How find it ? Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** There is an obvious solution of $(a, x, b, y) = (1, 1, 2, 2)$ or $(2, 2, 1, 1,)$, which gives us $x^a + y^b = 5$. We would **love** it if that were the only solutions.

**Hint:** Consider the recurrence relation, which tells us that the solution is uniquely determined (up to permuting the numbers). Define $ x_n = 1 + 2^{n+1}$. It is obvious (WHY??) that $x_n$ follows the recurrence relation

$$ x_{n+2} = 3x_{n+1} - 2 x_n$$

The theory of linear recurrence relation tells us that there is only 1 way to express this in terms of $ax^n + by^n$, hence the obvious solution is indeed the only solution.

---

Given china math's past questions, I believe he has enough ability to work through the above.

Comment: Wow, why the downvotes?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Cos nobody want to do any work. Shrug. This is becoming a "DO MY HOMEWORK NOW" site.

Comment: consider $$a_{n}=ax^n+by^n,\Longrightarrow a_{n+2}=(a+b)a_{n+1}-aba_{n}?$$, But my problem is find $x^a+y^b$, not find $a_{n}$

Comment: @chinamath That is easy to calculate once you know the solution set. See above edit.

Comment: why this solution is  only solution?

Comment: @chinamath See second hint.

Comment: I don't understand you hint,maybe I want consider $n\to\infty$,and use $q^n\to 0$ if $|q|<1$

Comment: Oh,I know,Thank you +1